# How do I cloudform an API gateway resource with a lambda proxy integration

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

I've been trying to work out how to express (in cloudformation) an API Gateway Resource that has a Lambda function integration type using the Lambda Proxy integration.

This is easy to do in the AWS console as there is a check box that you can select: 
[image: API gateway console showing the Use Lambda Proxy Integration checkbox]

However there is no corresponding field in the AWS::ApiGateway::Method CloudFormation resource (it should be in the [Integration property](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html)).

How can I configure this in cloudformation?

Comment: We're working on getting CloudFormation to update their docs, but as stated below you set the Integration Type to AWS_PROXY and also the HttpMethod to POST

Comment: You can see a working example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740949/lambda-permissions-error-when-setup-using-cloudformation-and-api-gateway-proxy/48752056#48752056

Comment: To me, it is simply insane that something that is so easy to do via the consoles is so hard to do using the "recommended" best practices cloud-formation route.

I suppose cloudformer was supposed to help fill this gap. A shame it is so very out of date.

Answer (score 22):

The Integration type should be set to `AWS_PROXY`. An example snippet of a method from a working YAML CloudFormation template is below.

```
ProxyResourceAny:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
  Properties:
    AuthorizationType: NONE
    HttpMethod: ANY
    ResourceId:
      Ref: ProxyResource
    RestApiId:
      Ref: API
    Integration:
      Type: AWS_PROXY
      IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
      Uri: !Sub
        - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${Arn}/invocations
        - Arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
            - RestorerLambda
            - Arn
```

It's worth saying how a I figured this out...

After scratching my head for a while I examined the output of the `aws apigateway get-method` CLI command for a method that was configured this way using the console. That gave me the following JSON and I realised that the checkbox might be encoded into the type. I tested my assumption and came up with the CloudFormation above.

```
{
    "apiKeyRequired": false,
    "httpMethod": "ANY",
    "methodIntegration": {
        "integrationResponses": {
            "200": {
                "responseTemplates": {
                    "application/json": null
                },
                "statusCode": "200"
            }
        },
        "passthroughBehavior": "WHEN_NO_MATCH",
        "cacheKeyParameters": [],
        "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:eu-west-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXX:function:Shildrew-Restorer-Play-Lambda/invocations",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "cacheNamespace": "64bl3tgw4g",
        "type": "AWS_PROXY"
    },
    "requestParameters": {},
    "authorizationType": "NONE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this same issue by simple changing the

```
Integration:
Type: AWS_PROXY
```

To

```
Integration:
Type: AWS
```

The cloud formation documentation currently is scarce and the API gateway cloudformation documentation doesn't match up to what can be seen on the console which hinders anyone who is trying to resolve an issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Isn't it the other way? i.e from AWS to AWS_PROXY? 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/api-reference/resource/integration/#type

Answer (score 1):

We faced this exact issue. We are using Ansible for our Infrastructure. Could apply to CLI or Cloudformation or even the SDK

The solution to our problem was to make sure that the Lambda policy was defined in a granular manner for the endpoint verbs in API Gateway for the lambda you are attempting to use.

For instance, We had multiple routes. Each route(or sets of routes) needs its own lambda policy defined that allows lambda:InvokeFunction. This is defined in the Lambda Policy module for Ansible. With this, the lambda trigger was enabled automatically.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this:

**Method 1: By defining the "Lambda", "API Gateway", "API Resource" and "API Methods". Linking the Lambda using the URI statement under "API Method".**

```
    MyLambdaFunction:
      Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
      Properties:
        Description: "Node.js Express REST API"
        FunctionName: "get_list_function" (The name in AWS console)
        Handler: lambda.handler
        Runtime: nodejs12
        MemorySize: 128
        Role: <ROLE ARN>
        Timeout: 60

      apiGateway:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi"
        Properties:
          Name: "example-api-gw"
          Description: "Example API"
    
      ProxyResource:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Resource"
        Properties:
          ParentId: !GetAtt apiGateway.RootResourceId
          RestApiId: !Ref apiGateway
          PathPart: '{proxy+}' OR "a simple string like "PetStore"
    
      apiGatewayRootMethod:
        Type: "AWS::ApiGateway::Method"
        Properties:
          AuthorizationType: NONE
          HttpMethod: ANY
          Integration:
            IntegrationHttpMethod: POST
            Type: AWS_PROXY
            IntegrationResponses:
              - StatusCode: 200
            Uri: !Sub >-
            arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${MyLambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations
          ResourceId: !Ref ProxyResource
          RestApiId: !Ref "apiGateway"
```

**METHOD 2: Define "API Gateway" and "Lambda". In Lambda definitions, call Events of type API.**

```
 CoreApi:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Api'
    Properties:
      StageName: dev
      Name: SaaSAPI 
      EndpointConfiguration: Regional
      Cors:
        AllowMethods: '''POST, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, DELETE, PUT'''
        AllowHeaders: '''Content-Type, X-Amz-Date, Authorization, X-Api-Key, x-requested-with'''
        AllowOrigin: '''*'''
        MaxAge: '''600'''

 MyLambdaFunction:
      Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
      Properties:
        Description: "Node.js Express REST API"
        FunctionName: "get_list_function"
        Handler: lambda.handler
        Runtime: nodejs12
        MemorySize: 128
        Role: <ROLE ARN>
        Timeout: 60
        Events:
          ProxyResourceA:
            Type: Api
            Properties:
              Path: /Departments
              Method: GET
              RestApiId: !Ref CoreApi

          ProxyResourceB: 
            Type: Api
            Properties:
              Path: /Departments (This becomes the resource in API Gateway)
              Method: POST
              RestApiId: !Ref CoreApi
```

(You can link multiple methods with the same lambda, provide a unique name to each event, like ProxyResoruceA & ProxyResourceB)